# Does iPhone3GS support block queues?

Tags: objective-c, core-motion, iphone-3gs

I'm running into a problem with some of my code on iPhone3GS running iOS5.0

**The following block never gets executed**, even though it gets called fine on iPhone4 with iOS5.0.

The log statement never appears, and the breakpoint never gets triggered. I checked, and both the motion manager and the queue are not null.

```
  [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"motion event received");

//...
}];
```

Am I missing something or do I need to re-write my code to work without block queues?
Thank you for any input on the ussue!

Update:

I've checked this method, and it works:

```
   [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:motionQueue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"accelerometerData event received");
    }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with block queues. I believe your problem is the device motion events require both accelerometer and gyroscope (and can be queried with `-deviceMotionAvailable`), but the iPhone 3GS doesn't have a gyroscope. So even the non-block-based device motion methods won't work for you. You should look into seeing if the accelerometer alone is sufficient for your needs; otherwise you'll have to restrict your app to require a gyroscope.